# Why doesn't @import work when at the end of the main CSS file?

Tags: html, css, import

Here's a minimal working example of what I'm experiencing:

#### index.html

```html
<head> <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"> </head>
<p> This is a test </p>
```

#### main.css

```css
p {color:purple;}
@import "background.css";
```

#### background.css

```css
p {background-color:yellow;}
```

Trying this in Vivaldi and Firefox, the style in `background.css` isn't applied. Shouldn't it be though? If I swap the two lines in `main.css`, @importing `background.css` first, it *does* get applied. But why would this matter? Shouldn't `background.css` be applied in either case?

Note this is the same issue being described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7641082/2671341) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70463369/2671341), but the answers there don't get at the heart of the question—they recommend importing in the correct order in the HTML file, bypassing this issue altogether.

Comment: it's described in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import)

Comment: @VilleKoo From what I can tell, it is not. I cannot find the requirement that `@imports` occur at the beginning of that style sheet in that page. I've made a pull request for that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As already defined in CSS1:](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/)

> In CSS1, all '@import' statements must occur at the start of a style
> sheet, before any declarations. **This makes it easy to see that rules
> in the style sheet itself override rules in the imported style sheets.**

Answer (score 1):

In CSS1 you should put the @import function  at the top of the document (but after any @charset declaration).

The css syntax should be:

```
@import url|string list-of-mediaqueries;
```

This can all be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_import_rule.php

Answer (score 1):

A style sheet that is imported into another one has a lower ranking in the cascading order: the importing style sheet overrides the imported one. Programmers may recognize this as the same model as in Java, Modula, Object-Pascal, Oberon and other modular programming languages.